# Why doesn't GCP's "Memorystore for Redis" doesnot allow option to add Public IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

Currently, when trying to create "MemoryStore for Redis" in GCP, there is no option to add Public IP.

This poses a problem as I am unable to connect to it from a Compute Engine from external network with this REDIS instance in another network.

Why is this missing?

Answer (score 2):

> Redis is designed to be accessed by trusted clients inside trusted
> environments. This means that usually it is not a good idea to expose
> the Redis instance directly to the internet or, in general, to an
> environment where untrusted clients can directly access the Redis TCP
> port or UNIX socket.

[Redis Security](https://redis.io/topics/security)

Answer (score 1):

I think because a design decision but in general this is not something we will know since we are not part of the Product team so I don't think this question can be easily answered in SO.

According to this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/148573830) there are no plans to support this a near future.

Said that you may want to take a look to at this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting_from_a_local_machine_with_port_forwarding) where it shows some workarounds to connect from a network outside the VPC.